# how to get sub-string using regex if I specify start and end including start and end

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string like 'String start &st This is the line > remaining'. I want a regex to find sub string starting from &st and ends with > including these like &st This is the line >
I tried this

```
(?<=&st).*?(?=>)
```

But this does not include the start and end specified (Here &st and >)
Any idea on this?  I am using this in Visual basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the lookround content in your pattern:

```
(&st.*?>)
```

If, for some reason, you really needed to use lookarounds, you can rework what you originally had:

```
(?=&st).*?(?<=>)
```

### Demo